# Is it possible to use a mixin for browser-specific CSS

Tags: browser, sass, mixins, vendor-prefix

I'm looking for a solution to use a mixin for browser-specific CSS hacks.
I'm using JavaScript to add the browser tag in the HTML class. Like `.ie .ie7 .ie8 .ie9`

I would like to use the mixin like:

```css
.box-test {
margin: 10px;
@include browser(ie7) {
    margin: 20px;
    }
}
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```css
.box-test {
margin: 10px;
}
.ie7 .box-test {
    margin: 20px;
    }
```

the mixin i tried to make:

```css
@mixin browser($browserVar) {
    @if $browserVar == ie7 {
    .ie7 { @content }
    }
    @else if $browserVar == ie8 {
    .ie8 { @content; }
         }
    @else if $browserVar == ie9 {
    .ie9 { @content; }
    }
}
```

the problem is the output is:

```css
.box-test {
    margin: 10px; }
.box-test .ie7 {
      margin: 20px; }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The absolute simplest mixin would be like so:

```
@mixin legacy-ie($ver: 7) {
    .ie#{$ver} & {
        @content;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
.baz {
    background: #CCC;

    @include legacy-ie {
        background: black;
    }
}
```

If you wanted to emit styles that work for multiple IE versions at once without duplication, then this would be one way to do it:

```
$default-legacy-ie: 7 8 9 !default;

@mixin legacy-ie($versions: $default-legacy-ie) {
    $sel: ();
    @each $v in $versions {
        $sel: append($sel, unquote('.ie#{$v} &'), comma);
    }

    #{$sel} {
        @content;
    }
}

.foo {
    background: red;

    @include legacy-ie {
        background: green;
    }
}

.bar {
    background: yellow;

    @include legacy-ie(7 8) {
        background: orange;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
.foo {
  background: red;
}
.ie7 .foo, .ie8 .foo, .ie9 .foo {
  background: green;
}

.bar {
  background: yellow;
}
.ie7 .bar, .ie8 .bar {
  background: orange;
}
```

If you want to be able to suppress all of the IE kludges all you need to add is one variable and an `@if` block:

```
$enable-legacy-ie: true !default;

@mixin legacy-ie($ver: 7) {
    @if $enable-legacy-ie {
        .ie#{$ver} & {
            @content;
        }
    }
}
```

Set `$enable-legacy-ie` to `false` at the top of the file you don't want to have the IE specific styles, set it to `true` if you do want the styles included.  You could easily write a reverse mixin to hide styles that old IE can't make use of so that the IE specific file stays nice and small.

Comment: Wow, that's a really good solution! thx! Maybe you can also find a solution for my rtl problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14199323/right-to-left-rtl-support-in-sass-project/14810260?noredirect=1#14810260

Answer (score 1):

You're overcomplicating things. :) It could be as simple as that:

```
.box-test {
  margin: 10px;

  .ie-7 & {
    margin: 20px; } }
```

Result:

```
.box-test {
  margin: 10px;
}
.ie-7 .box-test {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Personally, I prefer to use a mixin over simply writing out the selector because I would like to be able to generate individual CSS files: one without all of the ugly IE cludges and one with.  A mixin would let you do that easily, while writing out the selector by hand will not.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried adding mixin for "@-moz-document url-prefix()" FF hack but it was not recognized by SASS and SASS was throwing error. so I think better solution is to create _hack.sass file and add css hacks which will not be compiled by SASS. I include this file whenever required.

@import "hack";

I am adding answer this as I feel it will be useful to someone who is struggling to get mozilla/safari hack works.