# Use SASS to separate IE8 styles into separate stylesheet?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, sass, stylesheet

I have a SASS mixin rem() that converts pixel unit values into rems, but includes a px fallback for IE8. For example, calling the following:

```
@include rem((padding: 15px));
```

would generate something like:

```
padding: 15px;
padding: 1.071rem;
```

The problem is - for modern browsers, I don't want to include the px fallback, since it's adding an unnecessary line of CSS every single time the rem() mixin is used. So my question is:

**Question:** Is there a way for SASS (or SASS used with something else) to separate every px fallback into a separate ie stylesheet (say, "ie-8.css")?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiling and maintaining ie-specific stylesheets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135803/compiling-and-maintaining-ie-specific-stylesheets)

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967175/is-it-possible-to-use-a-mixin-for-browser-specific-css

Answer (score -1):

I don't think splitting SASS output is possible using SASS alone. You could probably write a funky little routine that scans your SASS for certain selectors as its rendered and process the output accordingly, but that's beyond my knowledge.

It's worth considering how much impact the fallback selector is really having on performance. Unused css selectors [have minimal impact](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/200955/are-unused-css-rules-so-costly-that-they-must-be-removed) on load times. On the other hand, an extra http request for an IE8 stylesheet, plus the time to apply that stylesheet after your base styles have loaded, is, I would think, a more demanding task. Whether or not that's an issue to you depends on how many IE8 users you're supporting.

A middle-road might be to apply [IE-specific classes to your `<html>` tag](http://www.paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/) or container, and altering your mixin so that the fallback is only applied when that conditional class is in effect.

HTML

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class=""> <!--<![endif]-->
```

SASS

```
@mixin rem($padding) {
    .ie8 & {
        padding: $padding;
    }
    padding: //calculate your rem value, or vice versa
}
```

I've put together a little [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C78gf/1/) to demonstrate the mixin.